# How the term "relational database" was chosen by E.F Codd

Tags: relational-database

> The term "relational database" was chosen by a scientist working at
>   IBM (E. F. Codd), because he had in mind his cousins and other
>   relations when thinking about how to organize his family tree.

I had this question in my exam. I guessed the answer as "no" but was not able to find any reference of it anywhere and my curiosity led me here. Can someone please confirm it? and provide a reference too.

Answer (score 1):

The relational model of data was described by Codd in his paper `A Relational Model of Data for Large Shared Data Banks`:

*1.3 A Relational View of Data*

*The term relation is used here in its accepted mathematical sense. Given sets S1, S2, ..., Sn (not necessarily distinct), R is a relation on these n sets if it is a set of n-tuples each of which has its first element from S1, its second element from S2, and so on.*